# How to figure out what's holding Node.js from exiting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, event-loop

I have this problem very often with various Node.js scripts that I write. After everything is done, they do not exit. Usually, it's an unclosed socket or readline interface.

When the script gets bigger, this is really hard to find out. Is there a tool of some sort that would tell me what's NodeJS waiting for? I'm asking for a generic solution that would help debug all cases of NodeJS not exiting when it's supposed to.

Samples:

#### Exhibit I. - Process stdin blocks node even after listener is removed

```
const readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
if (typeof process.stdin.setRawMode == "function")
    process.stdin.setRawMode(true);


const keypressListener = (stream, key) => {
    console.log(key);
    process.stdin.removeListener("keypress", keypressListener);
}
process.stdout.write("Press any key...");
process.stdin.on("keypress", keypressListener);
```

#### Exhibit II. - `readline` blocks Node if you forget to close the interface

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
```

#### Exhibit III. - Forgotten setInterval will also block node, good luck finding it

```
setInterval(() => { }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would [why-is-node-running](https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running) work? Seems to do exactly what you need.

Comment: It does work, although I think it has some false positives.